# How can i create and publish my own gem file like jar file in java

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

How can i create and publish my own gem file like jar file in java.

Any link or walk through or tutorial of steps to accomplish this task.

Comment: I have searched a lot but did not get proper steps. Got some links but as i am mostly a java developer i could not understand much. If you have steps to create gem of hello world or a+b program then you can share.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [this railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/245-new-gem-with-bundler?view=asciicast)
And [this rubygems tutorial](http://guides.rubygems.org/make-your-own-gem/)

Answer (score 1):

You likely want to use [bueller](https://github.com/dkastner/bueller). It creates `gemspec` file for you and then you are only to execute `gem build YOUGEMSPEC.gemspec`:

```
~ bueller PROJECT --summary "PROJECT SUMMARY" \
                  --user-name "" --user-email "" \
                  --github-username "" \
                  --homepage ""
# bueller’s output
~ gem build PROJECT.gemspec
```